# How do I train my Word2Vec model to firstly learn what each word means and then make a prediction on the corresponding price?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow, word2vec

I'm building a program that scrapes car information from a car trading website and then analyses the data to figure out if a car is underpriced/overpriced.

I want to created a model where I can parse details of a specific car, or a group of cars, in CSV form and the model will figure out if the cars are underpriced/overpriced and by what percentage, based on the information from the CSV, and give me a percentage accuracy for each of its predictions.

My CSV file has the headers:

CAR NAME, YEAR, MILEAGE, ATTENTION GRABBER, KEY SPECS, DESCRIPTION, URL, PRICE

So want to use Word2Vec to vectorize the text in the columns CAR NAME, ATTENTION GRABBER, KEY SPECS, DESCRIPTION. I have managed to do this for the first column, CAR NAME using the following method:

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()


df = pd.read_csv("data_utf-8.csv")
#train = df.sample(frac=0.8)
#test = df.drop(train.index)
train = df.iloc[0:12749,:]
test = df.drop(train.index)

train_car_name = train.iloc[:,0:1]
train_attention_grabber = train.iloc[:,1:2]
train_key_specs = train.iloc[:,2:3]
train_description = train.iloc[:,3:4]
train_url = train.iloc[:,4:5]
train_price = train.iloc[:,5:6]
# data_utf-8.csv does not have columns for year or mileage. 
# This is in another csv file that I will use later.


words = []
for r in range(0,12749):
    temp = []
    for word in nltk.tokenize.WhitespaceTokenizer().tokenize(train_car_name["CAR NAME"][r]):    #print(nltk.word_tokenize(train_car_name["CAR NAME"][r]))   <---- Another option.
        temp.append(word.lower())
    words.append(temp)
print(words)   #This is a list of lists

words_flat_list = [item for sublist in words for item in sublist]
#print(words_flat_list)              #This print statement is causing words to go out of order!!! I don't understand at all why!

def remove_duplicates(x):
  return list(dict.fromkeys(x))

words_list_no_dupes = remove_duplicates(words_flat_list)
print(words_list_no_dupes)


#word_set = set(words_flat_list)
#print(word_set)

word2int = {}
int2word = {}
vocab_size = len(words_list_no_dupes) # gives the total number of unique words      # could use len(words_list_no_dupes) or len(word_set)
for i,word in enumerate(words_list_no_dupes):
    word2int[word] = i
    int2word[i] = word
```

This code manages to vectorize the first column of my CSV. I could repeat the same process to vectorize the remaining columns or make a for loop to do it for me. I just haven't coded it in there yet. But I know what to do for that. Now that I have vectorized this first column however, how exactly do I train my model?

I understand that I could use the following code to get a bunch of word-word pairs...

```
#this next bit of code gives us a bunch of word, word pairs for training
data = []
WINDOW_SIZE = 2
for sentence in words:
    for word_index, word in enumerate(sentence):
        for nb_word in sentence[max(word_index - WINDOW_SIZE, 0) : min(word_index + WINDOW_SIZE, len(sentence)) + 1] :
            if nb_word != word:
                data.append([word, nb_word])
```

But i'm not really sure if I need to get these word-word pairs anyway? And if not then i'm a bit stuck as how to actually train the model.

Comment: `word2vec` is part of `glove` python package. Install it. Read docs or google for online tutorials.

Comment: I don't see any use of the `word2vec` algorithm in your code – which just seems to give each unique car-name a unique int index. In a way, that's a "one-hot" vector for the words – each word is represented by a wide vector where every dimension is `0.0`, except for its one int *i* index which is `1.0`. But actual `word2vec` modeling instead models words as shorter "dense" embedding vectors, where every dimension is non-zero, and words that are "more related" in the training text are closer to each other.

Comment: If that's what you were hoping for by talking about `word2vec`, you'll need to use a `word2vec` library, and train on texts that use multiple words near each other. (A single `name` field, corresponding to a car's make/model, won't work well as it's not like a set of rich sentences showing many subtly-contrasting examples of a word's usage around varying sets of neighboring words.)

Comment: I'll be honest I actually thought I was using word2vec as I thought that giving each car name a integer index was the first step in word2vec. I had thought that both dense embedding vectors and one hot vectors both fell under the category of word2vec.

Comment: So what would you advice would be the best method to train my model? And was there any point in giving each word a unique integer if I'm going to use dense embedding vectors? I'm very new to coding and this is my first project.

Comment: No, 'word2vec' typically means the algorithm for learning the short, dense vectors for words. (Just assigning words a unique 'slot' is an automatic step in many word2vec or natural-language-processing libraries, that you'd often not need to do yourself – it'll just happen, when learn the vocabulary of a corpus.)

Comment: Algorithmically predicting prices from other data is a fairly ambitious 1st project for a new coder, but if that's your interest, I'd look 1st at complete machine-learning tutorials that work on text, and either make a binary prediction ("is this an X or not?"), or classify the text into multiple categories ("is this an X, Y, or Z?"), or predict a single scalar value from text ("what's the value N expected from this example?"). That last task is most often called "regression", & you should find many online tutorials of "predict price from (house/etc) listing" - though many will be bad.